# postgresql installation failed with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, apt

I'm running on an AWS Ubuntu image.

In an attempt to set up my machine, I played around with apt-get to add and remove PostgreSql and some of its modules.

Now, when I run `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3` i get the following error:

```
Setting up postgresql-9.3 (9.3.10-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                                     * Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf" : No such file or directory
```

The only file/directory missing is `/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`

I tried:

1. Adding the directory
2. Removing postgresql with `sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3` and installing it again

The error still occurs.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you deleted the cluster when uninstalling and it isn't recreated automatically.

Recreating the cluster should solve the problem:

```
mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
chown postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
su postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main initdb
```

You may need to substitute *postgres* with the database user account that is used on ubuntu.

Checkout the postgres manual for more information:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html